# three level random coefficients in jags

Tags: multilevel-analysis

How do I specify a three-level model in Rjags with random intercepts and slopes.  I can’t find help anywhere, not even in Gelman and Hill, so hence this question:

In the model below, which is the simplest version of a rc-model in Gelman and Hill, I include a random intercept and slope at the second level and a random intercept at the third level, or at at least that's what I'm trying to do.  Putting `a3[level3[j]]` in the `y.hat[i]` equation gave the same disappointing result, more specifically:

```
RUNTIME ERROR:
Compilation error on line 3.
Unable to resolve node y.hat[1]


Any suggestions on how to proceed (or where to read), and perhaps even how to add random slopes at the third level?



model3 <- "model {
for(i in 1:N){
y[i] ~ dnorm(y.hat[i], tau.y)
y.hat[i] <- a[level2[i]] + b[level2[i]]*x1[i] + beta1*x2[i]
}

# Second level
for (j in 1:J){
a[j] <- B[j,1]
b[j] <- B[j,2]
B[j,1:2] ~ dmnorm(B.hat[j,], Tau.B[,])
B.hat[j,1] <- a3[level3[j]]
B.hat[j,2] 
}
tau.y <- pow(sigma.y, -2)
sigma.y ~ dunif(0, 100)
Tau.B[1:2,1:2] <- inverse(Sigma.B[,])
Sigma.B[1,1] <- pow(sigma.a, 2)
Sigma.B[2,2] <- pow(sigma.b, 2)
Sigma.B[1,2] <- rho*sigma.a*sigma.b
Sigma.B[2,1] <- Sigma.B[1,2]
sigma.a ~ dunif(0, 100)
sigma.b ~ dunif(0, 100)
rho ~ dunif(-1, 1)

### Third level 

for(t in 1:L){                        
a3[t] ~ dnorm(0, tau.a3)

}
tau.a3 <- pow(sigma.a1, -2)
sigma.a3 ~ dunif(0, 100)


mu.b ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
mu.a ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
beta1 ~ dnorm(0, .0001)

}"
write(model, file="model.bug")
```